# RecyclerView binding with LiveData displaying wrong values after item is removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I'm using a RecyclerView with LiveData and databinding. The user can remove elements from the recyclerview, and sometimes, after an item is removed, the items in the list are reordered incorrectly and the wrong item is removed.

In printing the values in LogCat, the correct values/order are always printed, so it's somewhere in the display/binding that the items are getting (I believe) recycled improperly, but I haven't been able to resolve it.

Here's what I'm working with: Fragment, ViewModel, ItemPresenter, Adapter, list_item.xml
Below are what I believe to be the relevant parts of each file:

**Fragment**

```
        viewModel
                .personalFilesLiveData
                .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                    personalFilesAdapter.bind(it)
                    if(personalFilesAdapter.itemCount == 0){
                        this.activity?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.no_results_container)?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    else{
                        this.activity?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.no_results_container)?.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                })
```

**Presenter**

```
class ItemPresenter(
    private val openContentAction: (String) -> Unit,
    private val removePersonalFileAction: (String) -> Unit) {

    private lateinit var myPersonalFile: MyPersonalFileData

    val name get() = myPersonalFile.name
    val fileName get() = myPersonalFile.fileName
    val month get() = myPersonalFile.monthDay
    val year get() = myPersonalFile.year

    fun bind(file: MyPersonalFileData) {
        Log.d("MyFilesPersonalFileItemPresenter", "name: " + file.name)
        this.myPersonalFile = file
    }

    fun contentClicked() {
        openContentAction(myPersonalFile.contentId)
    }

    fun removeClicked() {
        removePersonalFileAction(myPersonalFile.contentId)
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
class Adapter(
    private val openContentAction: (String) -> Unit,
    private val removePersonalFileAction: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DataboundViewHolder<ViewMyPersonalFilesItemBinding>>() {

    private var data = emptyList<MyPersonalFileData>()

    fun bind(data: List<MyPersonalFileData>) {
        val diff = RecyclerViewDiffHelper.simpleDiffUtil(this.data, data) {
            first, second -> first.contentId == second.contentId
        }
        this.data = data
        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataboundViewHolder<ViewMyPersonalFilesItemBinding> {
        return DataboundViewHolder(
            ViewMyPersonalFilesItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false).apply {
                presenter = MyFilesPersonalFileItemPresenter(openContentAction, removePersonalFileAction)
            }
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = data.count()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataboundViewHolder<ViewMyPersonalFilesItemBinding>, position: Int) {
        AlternateBackgroundHelper.setBackground(holder.binding.root, position)
        holder.binding.presenter?.bind(data[position])
    }
}

class MyPersonalFileData(
    val name: String,
    val fileName: String,
    val monthDay: String,
    val year: String,
    val contentId: String


) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "MyPersonalFileData(name='$name')"
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="com.storyslab.helper.myfiles.bookmarks.MyFilesBookmarkItemPresenter" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.contentClicked()}"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        tools:background="#313131">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@{presenter.name}"
            app:fontFamily="@font/oswald_regular"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_date_top_line"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_file_name"
            tools:text="Content Name" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within this portion of your code in the adapter:

```
private var data = emptyList<MyPersonalFileData>()

fun bind(data: List<MyPersonalFileData>) {
    val diff = RecyclerViewDiffHelper.simpleDiffUtil(this.data, data) {
        first, second -> first.contentId == second.contentId
    }
    this.data = data // PROBLEM HERE!
    diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

You're replacing the main list of the adapter with the list that comes from your activity/fragment. In my opinion, we should never expose the same list reference to the adapter this way. Doing this may cause unexpected results like the one you're facing here.

Try like this and your problem should be resolved:

```
private val data = mutableListOf<MyPersonalFileData>()

fun bind(data: List<MyPersonalFileData>) {
    val diff = RecyclerViewDiffHelper.simpleDiffUtil(this.data, data) {
        first, second -> first.contentId == second.contentId
    }
    this.data.clear()
    this.data.addAll(data)
    diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. Just replace the bind method and the data list with the following list.

```
 private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)

fun bind(newList: List<Operator>) {
    differ.submitList(newList)
}

companion object {
    private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Operator>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyPersonalFileData, newItem: MyPersonalFileData): Boolean =
            oldItem.contentId == newItem.contentId 

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Operator, newItem: Operator): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```